# Android - Check Switch State by reading file

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to check get my switch to check (read) a file in a kernel path and set the state at app launch. The possible values are just 0 or 1. 0 means the switch should show as "off"... 1 mean as "on".

My code does not seem to be working though... can someone help me troubleshoot?

Code:

```
mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

        //Switch check
        List<String> stdout = Shell.SU.run("cat " + Files.DT2W_PATH);
        for (String s : stdout) {
            if (Integer.valueOf(s) == 0)
                continue;
            mySwitch.setChecked(false);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

    //Switch check
    List<String> stdout = Shell.SU.run("cat " + Files.DT2W_PATH);
    for (String s : stdout) {
        if (Integer.valueOf(s) == 0){
            continue;
        mySwitch.setChecked(false);

    }else{
myswitch.setChecked(true);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you, 1 more question: how do I adapt this for multiple checks if I have multiple toggle switches?

Comment: Add you have to do is instantiate your new switches (like you did above) and place them into the code specifying the state you want them to be in if() something happends and how you want them to be otherwise else();

Comment: that does not seem to work as they just get overwritten by the first statement... any way to provide a sample code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
secondSwitch = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.secondSwitch);

//Switch check
List<String> stdout = Shell.SU.run("cat " + Files.DT2W_PATH);
for (String s : stdout) {
    if (Integer.valueOf(s) == 0){
        continue;
    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
    secondSwitch.setChecked(true or false);

}else{
myswitch.setChecked(true);
secondSwitch.setChecked(true);
}}
```

When you say "adapt this for multiple checks if I have multiple toggle switches" I take it as having more than one checkbox in an activity.